# Unable to display thumbnails in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionreusableview

I am trying to recreate this [thing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUXDb.png). I've created in Storyboard [skeleton](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VCyP.png). Here's the idea of my code:

1. Fetch images from URL's array with help of the function **getThumbnailFromImage**
2. Add UIImage's with my thumbnails in array **webImages**
3. Add in **ViewController** reusable cell **MyCollectionView**
4. ...

But here I am with [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dgUB.png)))) (Don't mind absence of Auto Layout). What am I doing wrong? I think that the problem is with reloadData() but I don't know where to put it.

ViewController:

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  youtube-clone
//
//  Created by мас on 16.08.2022.
//

import Foundation
import UIKit
import YouTubePlayer
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    
    var url: [URL?] = [
        URL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KhebpuFBD14"),
        URL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UfNdNrRHpUw"),
        URL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CX-BdDHW0Ho"),
        URL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NIOMtSzfpck")
    ]
    
    var webImages: [UIImage] = []
    
    var currentPage: Int = 0
    
    @IBOutlet var myPage: UIPageControl!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonInfo: UIButton!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        setupLayout()
        
        myPage.currentPage = 0
        myPage.numberOfPages = webImages.count
        
    }
    
    // MARK: - Collection View Setup
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return webImages.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
         
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! MyCollectionCell
        
        getThumbnailFromImage(url: url[indexPath.row]!, completion: { image in
            self.webImages.append(image!)
        })
        
        cell.myWebImage.image = webImages[indexPath.row]
        
        cell.myWebImage.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        
        return cell
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        myPage.currentPage = indexPath.row
    }
    
    // MARK: - Layout Setup // IGNORE IT
    
    func setupLayout() {
        
        buttonInfo.layer.cornerRadius = 25
        
        buttonInfo.imageView!.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 180 * .pi / 180)
        
        
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
    }
    
    // MARK: - Videos Thumbnail Fetcher
    func getThumbnailFromImage(url: URL, completion: @escaping ((_ image: UIImage?) -> Void)) {
        
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            let asset = AVAsset(url: url)
            let avAssetImageGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
            avAssetImageGenerator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
            
            let thumbnailTime = CMTimeMake(value: 7, timescale: 1)
            do {
                let cgThumbImage = try avAssetImageGenerator.copyCGImage(at: thumbnailTime, actualTime: nil)
                let thumbImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgThumbImage)
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(thumbImage)
                }
            }
            catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

Reusable Cell AKA MyCollectionCell:

```
import UIKit

class MyCollectionCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet var myWebImage: UIImageView!
    
}
```

P.s.: YouTubePlayer is custom pod from GitHub, it's not currently used.

Comment: `getThumbnailFromImage` is asynchronous. That means it returns no result, but rather calls its completion handler _at some time in the future_. That future is _after_ your `cellForItemAt` has returned. Therefore you can't call it in this way in this place. You need to revise your whole cell configuration architecture. You could _try_ calling `reload` right after `self.webImages.append(image!)` inside the completion handler, but my feeling is that that might break down while scrolling rapidly; still, give it a try and see if things are any better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do NOT have to use `AVAssetImageGenerator`, Simply you can use Youtube API to fetch the thumbnail images as `.jpg` image by video id,
and each YouTube video has four generated images.

```
https://img.youtube.com/vi/{id}/0.jpg
https://img.youtube.com/vi/{id}/1.jpg
https://img.youtube.com/vi/{id}/2.jpg
https://img.youtube.com/vi/{id}/3.jpg
```

Example
https://img.youtube.com/vi/KhebpuFBD14/0.jpg

And then it is preferred to use a third party to load this image as its displayed in a list, like https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage or https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher and you will NOT be worry about Concurrency or caching.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of thoughts:

1. @matt is right in the comment - `getThumbnailFromImage` will likely not have called the completion block by the time `cellForItemAt` returns.
2. From what is visible in the code you posted, `webImages.count` will still be 0 when your collection view checks `numberOfItemsInSection`. If the number of items is 0, `cellForItemAt` may never get called so the call to `getThumbnailFromImage` wouldn't even be reached. (I'm not sure if the white box in your screenshot is part of a cell or another view element. If a cell is being displayed, I'm assuming you're populating `webImages` somewhere else before the collection view gets laid out).

One way you could work around these issues is by giving each cell a URL rather than a thumbnail. That way the cell can be displayed while the image is still loading. The cell could look something like this:

```
class MyCollectionCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var myWebImage: UIImageView!

    func configure(urlString: String) {
       guard let self = self, let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
           return
       }

       getThumbnailFromImage(url: url, completion: { [weak self] image in
           self?.myWebImage.image = image
       })
    }

    // Move `getThumbnailForImage` function to here, or give the cell a delegate to call back to the VC with if you don't want any networking in the view itself
}
```

The `cellForItemAt` function in the VC would need to be changed to something like this:

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
     
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! MyCollectionCell
    
    cell.configure(urlString: url[indexPath.row])
            
    cell.myWebImage.layer.cornerRadius = 20 // This should probably live in the cell since the parent doesn't actually need to know about it!
    
    return cell
}
```

An added benefit of this approach is that you're not referencing a separate array of images that could theoretically end up being in the wrong order if there's a mistake somewhere in the code. You could get rid of the `webImages` array entirely and use `urls.count` in `numberOfItemsInSection` instead - or eventually the number of elements returned from an API somewhere.

Side note - make sure you add `[weak self]` at the beginning of any closure that references `self` to avoid trying to access it after it's been deallocated! Currently the call to `getThumbnailFromImage` doesn't have that :)

Also, note that I changed to a `guard` statement for checking that the URL exists. This is much safer than force unwrapping a URL(string:) value, especially if you ever end up getting the strings from a dynamic source.